# Kendo UI Combobox - Get selected value

Tags: knockout.js, kendo-ui, kendo-combobox

I want the selected value of kendo combobox with knockout. I have tried using
 var selectedItem = this.dataItem(e.item.index()),In select method, which is returning the correct value. But after closing the dropdown, it is displaying previously selected item. Is there any other way to set the selected value for kendo combobox.

Answer (score 0):

You need a custom binding handler. See [here](https://rniemeyer.github.io/knockout-kendo/web/ComboBox.html).